# ROS-kinetic (C++11) resource retriever undefined references

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to get an MySQL query from a  file. For that I a trying to use [this example](http://wiki.ros.org/resource_retriever/Tutorials/Retrieving%20Files). But when I have `resource_retriever::Retriever r;` in the code, I get the following errors.

`resource_retriever::Retriever r;` is the line causing the error and I don't get it. Any idea? (The header files are included and the files are present - I checked)

```
[ 95%] Building CXX object xxxxx/CMakeFiles/xxxxx.dir/src/xxxxx.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/teshanl/catkin_ws/devel/lib/xxxxxx/xxxxxx
CMakeFiles/xxxxxx.dir/src/xxxxxx.cpp.o: In function `main':
xxxxx.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `resource_retriever::Retriever::Retriever()'
xxxxx.cpp:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `resource_retriever::Retriever::get(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const
&)'
xxxxx.cpp:(.text+0x1a0): undefined reference to `resource_retriever::Retriever::~Retriever()'
xxxxx.cpp:(.text+0x243): undefined reference to `resource_retriever::Retriever::~Retriever()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
xxxxx/CMakeFiles/xxxxx.dir/build.make:117: recipe for target '/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/devel/lib/xxxxx' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/teshanl/catkin_ws/devel/lib/xxxxx] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1836: recipe for target 'xxxxx/CMakeFiles/xxxxxx.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [xxxxx/CMakeFiles/xxxxxx.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302557/ros-kinetic-(c++11)-resource-retriever-undefined-references/) by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2018-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems like a linker error. How are you linking the `resource_retriever` libraries? Can you show your `CMakeLists.txt`?

---

Edit:

> Adding `resource_retriever` to `find_package` did the trick. But still when I include something like this, how do I know what to add to the `CMakeLists.txt`

As to your specific question "what to add to `CMakeLists.txt`": in case of C++ and Python the rule is relatively straightforward: if you use anything from a package, that package becomes a *dependency* of your package.

In those cases you have to add the dependency to your `package.xml` and your `CMakeLists.txt` *if you are working in C++*.

If you are using Python, only the `package.xml` needs to be updated (as Python doesn't have any build dependencies (or at least: regular, simple Python packages don't)).

See [the Catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/catkin_library_dependencies.html) on the general subject.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-06**:
I guess you haven't specified the the `CMakeLists.txt` correctly. Make sure you have set this up correctly in the `find_package` part. Please post the `CMakeLists.txt` to get more help.
...
What @gvdhoorn said :-D

**Comment by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on 2018-09-06**:
Yes I didn't do any edit to the `CMakeLists.txt`. What should I add? And when I include something like this, how do I know what to add to the `CMakeLists.txt`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-06**:
Please show us your current `CMakeLists.txt`, then we can suggest edits.

But in general, see [the Catkin documentation](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/catkin_library_dependencies.html) on that subject.

**Comment by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on 2018-09-06**:
Adding `resource_retriever` to `find_package` did the trick. But still when I include something like this, how do I know what to add to the `CMakeLists.txt`

**Comment by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on 2018-09-06**:
@gvdhoom Sorry this is work related so I can't share files without some redaction which takes time :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-06**:\

> Sorry this is work related so I can't share files without some redaction

Then the accepted workflow would be to create an MWE that exhibits the same problem but does not contain anything "work related".

But that is not necessary here, as I believe we've found the issue.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-09-06**:
Just for reference MWE=[minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example). See also [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)